# Number of elements in $S_8$ which are commutative with $(123)(456)$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many elements of the group $S_8$ are commutative with cycles composition $(123)(456)$

Let $\tau = (123)(456)$. It is clear that $\tau^{-1} = \tau^2$. Then if $\sigma$ is commutative with $\tau \iff \tau^2 \sigma \tau = \sigma.$ Transposition $(78)$, $\tau$ itself, cycles $(123)$, $(456)$ and any their product are commutative. How I can find other elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $\sigma \in S_8$. Then what is $\sigma^{-1}\tau \sigma$? There is a nice formula for that, and once you have that, you can easily write down all $\sigma$ such that you get $\tau$ here.

Comment: @Bemte Do you mean use the fact that conjunction preserve cycle structure and $\sigma^{-1} \tau \sigma = \tau$?

Comment: Why does it preserve cycle structure? Can you write down the cycles of $\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ for arbitrary $\sigma$?

Comment: @Bemte For $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$ it is $(\sigma (1) \sigma (2) \sigma(3))(\sigma(4) \sigma (5) \sigma (6))$

Comment: Indeed. Now you should be able to classify all $\sigma$ for which this will be exactly $\tau$.

Comment: @Bemte Yes, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In general, number of elements in $S_n$ that commute with $f$ is $$1^{a_1}\cdot 2^{a_2}\cdots n^{a_n} a_1!a_2! \cdots a_n!$$ where $a_i$ is the number of cycles of length $i$ in $f$.

Now $\tau=(7)(8)(123)(456)$. Therefore number of elements in $S_8$ that commute with $\tau$ is$$1^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 2!\cdot2!=36$$

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWoods.